# Why is fabric using /bin/sh

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to run some commands on a remote server. I need to source some bash files there. Unfortunately, it seems fabric has (suddenly, recently?) started using `/bin/sh`, and it breaks because I use bash syntax in my scripts. I have found [this](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run):

> If shell is True (the default), run will execute the given command string via a shell interpreter, the value of which may be controlled by setting env.shell (defaulting to something similar to /bin/bash -l -c "".) Any double-quote (") or dollar-sign ($) characters in command will be automatically escaped when shell is True.

I have not changed env.shell, so I do not know why fabric starts using `sh`. In any case, I am overwriting it, but still no luck:

```
env.shell = "/bin/bash"
```

What could be causing this? What can I do to *force* fabric to use `bash`?

Comment: Are you sure that bash is installed and `/bin/sh` points to it on the remote site?

Comment: `/bin/bash` is indeed installed. `/bin/sh` points to `dash` (wtf!), but anyway I want to use `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`, so it is not relevant where `/bin/sh` is pointing to.

Comment: Have you recently started running it under a different environment? For example, as `root` or `nobody` or `cgi` or similar instead of yourself? Or, alternatively, are you trying to `sudo` anything (fabric has code that specifically tries to emulate dropping env for sudo)?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you look at [the source](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py#L608) (or start [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py#L947) and trace your way to `_shell_wrap`), you can see exactly what it's doing, and I can't see how it could put anything but `env.shell` in there.

Comment: As for the wtf: Most linux distros used to use `bash` as their `sh`. Some *BSD systems used `ash` instead, because it's much smaller, doesn't change as often, and has been more thoroughly scrubbed for security issues (although still not enough for OpenBSD). At some point, for the same reasons, Debian (and therefore Ubuntu) switched from `bash` to a fork of `ash`, which was named to `dash` (guess what the `d` stands for).

Comment: Anyway, if you're writing code that requires bash features, even in environments where that isn't the default, you may want to explicitly run `bash` (with `shell=False`).

Comment: @abarnert: thanks for your comments. Do you have any idea how to force fabric to show the *full* command that it is executing? Ideal would be if I can see the *full* ssh command, including any flags and where the remote command being called is visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took some digging, but this is what I found:

It is possible to see what fabric is doing behind the scenes:

```
from   fabric.api                                        import output

FAB_SHOW_RUNNING  = True   # Show the command that fabric runs
FAB_SHOW_STDOUT   = False  # Show the stdout of the command run
FAB_SHOW_STDERR   = False  # Show the stderr of the command run
FAB_SHOW_DEBUG    = True   # Increase logging detail for messages
FAB_SHOW_USER     = True
FAB_SHOW_STATUS   = False  # Prevent fabric from using print in some situations (at least in disconnect_all)
FAB_SHOW_WARNINGS = False  # Avoid fabric from showing messages about failed commands

output['running']  = FAB_SHOW_RUNNING
output['stdout']   = FAB_SHOW_STDOUT
output['stderr']   = FAB_SHOW_STDERR
output['debug']    = FAB_SHOW_DEBUG
output['user']     = FAB_SHOW_USER
output['status']   = FAB_SHOW_STATUS
output['warnings'] = FAB_SHOW_WARNINGS
```

It turned out it is not fabric using `/bin/sh` but, since I was (in this particular case) running local commands, the culprit was the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) module. In order to specify the shell to be used, you need to specify `shell=True` and `executable='/bin/bash'`

Comment: What was your solution? No fabric [operation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html) accepts an "executable" parameter.